# WebAPI - FluentValidation - Validate Child model properties based on parent model value

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpateDate { get; set; }
    public IList<ChildClass> ChildList { get; set; }
}

public class ParentClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentClass>
{
    public ParentClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ParentId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Parent Id cannot be empty");
        When(x => x.ParentId == 1, () =>
          {
              RuleFor(x => x.ActivityId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Activity To cannot be empty.");
              RuleFor(x => x.ChildList).SetCollectionValidator(new ChildClassValidator().Validate(new ChildClass(), "ParentId1"));
          });
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

}

public class ChildClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildClass>
{
    public ChildClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Child Id cannot be empty");
        RuleSet("ParentId1", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.DueDate).Must(date => date != default(DateTime)).WithMessage("Due date cannot be empty");
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to validate the list of child based on the parent model property value.

I need to validate the common rules and also specific ruleset of ALL the childs from the parent. I tried the below code  `RuleFor(x => x.ChildList).SetCollectionValidator(new ChildClassValidator().Validate(new ChildClass(), "ParentId1"));` in parent validator but is not allowed

I went through [Child Model Validation using Parent Model Values. Fluent Validation. MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720105/child-model-validation-using-parent-model-values-fluent-validation-mvc4) but it is for only one property.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Validator(typeof(ParentClassValidator))]
public class ParentClass
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpateDate { get; set; }
    public IList<ChildClass> ChildList { get; set; }
}

public class ParentClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentClass>
{
    public ParentClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ParentId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Parent Id cannot be empty");
        When(x => x.ParentId == 1, () =>
        {
              RuleFor(x => x.ActivityId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Activity To cannot be empty.");
        });
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<ParentClass> context)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildList).SetCollectionValidator(new ExtMobileTransactionDataValidator(context.InstanceToValidate));
        return base.Validate(context);
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

}

public class ChildClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildClass>
{
    public ChildClassValidator(ParentClass parent)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Child Id cannot be empty");
        if(parent.ParentId == 1)
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.DueDate).Must(date => date != default(DateTime)).WithMessage("Due date cannot be empty");
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to achieve it by overriding the Validate method.

Remember to remove the Validator attribute for child class if the child class will not be validated individually else it will throw "No parameterless constructor defined" error.